# wrong item changes in recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Hi everyone I'm stuck in this and need help :

Each item has a `CheckBox` and I set `setOnLongClickListener` for root element of my items in `RecyclerView` like this :

```
    holder.faviorateVideoItemRelative.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        public boolean onLongClick(View arg0) {


            if (chk_visible)
            {
                return  true ;
            }
            holder.chk_faviorateVideo.setChecked(!holder.chk_faviorateVideo.isChecked());
            chk_visible = true ;
            checkedItemsCNT = 1 ;
            deleteListVideoCourses.add(data.get(holder.getAdapterPosition())) ;
            notifyDataSetChanged() ;
            return  true ;
        }
    });
```

If I scroll down , when I make a long click on one of items , the `CheckBox` of wrong item get checked !

Comment: post your full adapter code or getView method code plz

Comment: @배준모 too much codes ...

Comment: see @Doomsknight answer. that is same my idea

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It because as you use `RecycleView` it reuse your view every time when you scroll. `RecycleView` reuse your resource like this
[image]

So when you scroll it's showing the wrong state of your view

### Solution

If you write any logic for check-in `onBindViewHolder` then you have to use both part for true and false

```
if(yourCondition){
   //code if condition is true
}else {
   //code if condition is false
}
```

### Other Solution

Simply you can solve it just using one statement to stop your `RecycleView` to reuse your view state like this

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ReqNotificationAdapter.MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

    holder.setIsRecyclable(false);
    //.................your other code
}
```

I use it to solve my problem.. hope it will solve yours if you don't have a problem stop Recycling with your purpose.

Comment: I did that but in this way no CheckBox get checked !

Comment: holder.setIsRecyclable(false);

Comment: and for first one : what should I check to ensure Im checking currect CheckBox ?

Comment: If you do so it think you need to edit your condition .... let me check

Comment: what is purpose of "chk_visible". Do you want only can check the Check box?

Comment: checking visibility of checkBox

Comment: If you apply my solution then try removing code "if (chk_visible) {return  true; }" I think it is preventing you to check the check box...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148871/discussion-between-user3422607-and-enamul-haque).

Comment: You're an amazing guy, the `holder.setIsRecyclable(false);` solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Could be an issue in your bind rather than setting of the value.

A common mistakes is not un-checking the view in the bind.

Make sure where you are setting checked, you have an else statement and set it to unchecked.

RecyclerView and Listview reuse views as they scroll, which includes any previously checked boxes. So it is important to un-check them if appropriate.

```
public void bindView(View view,   ..... //varies on implementation. rough idea.
{
  CheckBox mycheckbox = (CheckBox)view.findViewById(R.id.myidofcheckbox);


  int pos = view.getPosition();

  if(pos == 1) //example
     mycheckbox.setChecked(true);
  else
     mycheckbox.setChecked(false);
```

Comment: so if condition is position how should I check currect position checkBox now ?

Comment: @user3422607 you should have a method `bindView(View view, ..`  in which you can call `int pos = view.getPosition();` Then check pos and act accordingly.

Comment: that's exactly the problem , first : positin is correct ! 
second : how should I check correct items checkBox  (correct position)   ?

Comment: I mean how you can I access CheckBox in position x ?!

Comment: @user you can search for the checkbox in the binded view `CheckBox mycheckbox = (CheckBox)view.findViewById(R.id.myidofcheckbox);`

Comment: OMG , the position is the matter !

Comment: @user3422607 That will give you the checkbox at that position, of the view it is currently binding. As you scroll, it binds each checkbox, in the next position. Giving you access to all the checkboxes in ever position as its being bound.

Comment: @user3422607 set the `setOnLongClickListener` inside the bind, don't use holder for now. Use `view` that comes with the method.

Answer (score 1):

Solution 1:

You can override two method getItemId, getItemViewType.

```
    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return position;
    }
```

Like this:

```
public class EasyAdapter  extends RecyclerView.Adapter<EasyAdapter.ViewHolder>{


    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return position;
    }
}
```

Solution 2:
Set setIsRecyclable false.

```
EasyAdapter easyAdapter=new EasyAdapter();
easyAdapter.setIsRecyclable(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it happens with ListView and RecyclerView

Try this code,

```
 holder.faviorateVideoItemRelative.setTag(position);
 holder.faviorateVideoItemRelative.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
    public boolean onLongClick(View arg0) {

        int tempPos = (int)holder.faviorateVideoItemRelative.getTag();

        if (chk_visible)
        {
            return  true ;
        }

         if(!holder.chk_faviorateVideo.isChecked())
         {
             holder.chk_faviorateVideo.setChecked(true);
         }
         else
         {
             holder.chk_faviorateVideo.setChecked(false);
         }

    holder.chk_faviorateVideo.setChecked(!holder.chk_faviorateVideo.isChecked());
        chk_visible = true ;
        checkedItemsCNT = 1 ;
        deleteListVideoCourses.add(data.get(tempPos)) ;
        notifyDataSetChanged() ;
        return  true ;
    }
});
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: my problem is this part : 
 holder.chk_faviorateVideo.setChecked(!holder.chk_faviorateVideo.isChecked());

Comment: You have to create a model class where you will take a boolean variable isChecked, it will managed your check box visibility. you can take this as refference http://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/07/android-listview-checkbox-example.html

Answer (score 0):

When you initialize your OnLongClickListener, it is reused in views when they are no longer visible because they are cached.
To solve the worry, create a new class to explicitly link an object to a listener and not just the view.
For example :

```
private class BufferVideoLongClickListener implements View.OnLongClickListener {

    private VideoObject video; // And other stuff like checked, etc

    BufferVideoLongClickListener(VideoObject video, ...) {
        this.video = video;
        ...
    }

    @Override
    public void onLongClick(View view) {
        // Do your check and other things
        if(checked)
          ...
    }
}
```

And in your onBindViewHolder :

```
holder.faviorateVideoItemRelative.setOnLongClickListener(new BufferVideoLongClickListener(video, ...));
```

Comment: I should pass the checkbox and holder give me checkbox at wrong position

Comment: You must use the holder only to store the views of an item. The check must be in the object you want to display. And as Doomsknight says, only uses the view parameter of the bind method.

Answer (score 0):

After using the above mentioned solutions,

The following solutions worked like a charm for me.

```
 @Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return position;
}
```

using `holder.setIsRecyclable(false)` removes the desired selection as well when you come back to it after the whole scrolling process.