# get wrong position recyclerview after searchview.onQueryTextListener

Tags: java, android-studio, android-recyclerview, searchview

Result of Searchview is OK but when i click the Recycleview it give the wrong position. example: when i search Padang, its show the result of "Padang" but when i click the Recyclerview it give me the data of the previous position Recyclerview.

When I click on the third Recycleview in the List, the UI returns the third Recycleview from the original List and not the third Recycleview from the filtered List. What am I missing here?

**RecyclerViewAdapter**

```
import android.app.DownloadManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.support.v7.widget.PopupMenu;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Filter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.toolbox.ImageLoader;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView;
import com.example.android.perpustakaanbpspadang.R;

import org.w3c.dom.Text;

import java.util.ArrayList;


public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    public Context context;
    ArrayList<GetDataAdapter> getDataAdapter = new ArrayList<GetDataAdapter>();
    ImageLoader imageLoader1;
    DownloadManager downloadManager;

    public RecyclerViewAdapter(ArrayList<GetDataAdapter> getDataAdapter, Context context){

        super();
        this.getDataAdapter = getDataAdapter;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_buku, parent, false);

        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(v, context, getDataAdapter);

        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder Viewholder, final int position) {

        final GetDataAdapter getDataAdapter1 =  getDataAdapter.get(position);

        imageLoader1 = ServerImageParseAdapter.getInstance(context).getImageLoader();

        imageLoader1.get(getDataAdapter1.getImageServerUrl(),
                ImageLoader.getImageListener(
                        Viewholder.networkImageView,//Server Image
                        R.mipmap.bps,//Before loading server image the default showing image.
                        android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert //Error image if requested image dose not found on server.
                )
        );

        Viewholder.networkImageView.setImageUrl(getDataAdapter1.getImageServerUrl(), imageLoader1);
        Viewholder.ImageTitleNameView.setText(getDataAdapter1.getImageTitleName());
        Viewholder.Rilis.setText(getDataAdapter1.getRilis());

        Viewholder.buttonViewOption.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(context, Viewholder.buttonViewOption);
                popup.inflate(R.menu.buku_menu);
                popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                        switch (item.getItemId()) {
                            case R.id.menu1:
                                if (isConnectingToInternet()) {
                                    downloadManager = (DownloadManager) context.getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
                                    Uri uri = Uri.parse(getDataAdapter1.getDownload());
                                    DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(uri);
                                    request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, getDataAdapter1.getImageTitleName() + ".pdf");
                                    request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
                                    Long reference = downloadManager.enqueue(request);
                                }
                                else {
                                    Toast.makeText(context, "Oops!! There is no internet connection. " +
                                            "Please enable internet connection and try again.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                                break;
                        }
                        return false;
                    }
                });
                popup.show();
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return getDataAdapter.size();
    }

    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

        public TextView ImageTitleNameView;
        public NetworkImageView networkImageView ;
        public TextView buttonViewOption;
        public TextView Rilis;
        ArrayList<GetDataAdapter> getDataAdapter = new ArrayList<GetDataAdapter>();
        Context context;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView, Context context, ArrayList<GetDataAdapter> getDataAdapter) {

            super(itemView);
            this.getDataAdapter = getDataAdapter;
            this.context = context;
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);

            ImageTitleNameView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView_item) ;
            networkImageView = (NetworkImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.VollyNetworkImageView1) ;
            buttonViewOption = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewOptions);
            Rilis = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView_rilis);

        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            int position = getAdapterPosition();
            GetDataAdapter perpus = this.getDataAdapter.get(position);
            final String image = this.getDataAdapter.get(position).getImageServerUrl();
            Intent intent = new Intent(this.context, DetailActivity.class);

            intent.putExtra("id", perpus.getIdBuku());
            intent.putExtra("judul", perpus.getImageTitleName());
            intent.putExtra("no_publikasi", perpus.getNomorPublikasi());
            intent.putExtra("no_katalog", perpus.getNomorKatalog());
            intent.putExtra("isbn", perpus.getISBN());
            intent.putExtra("deskripsi", perpus.getDeskripsi());
            intent.putExtra("file", perpus.getDownload());
            intent.putExtra("rilis", perpus.getRilis());
            intent.putExtra("kategori_id", perpus.getKategori());
            this.context.startActivity(intent);
        }
    }

    //Check if internet is present or not
    private boolean isConnectingToInternet() {
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo networkInfo = connectivityManager
                .getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected())
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    public void setFilter (ArrayList<GetDataAdapter> newList){
        getDataAdapter = new ArrayList<GetDataAdapter>();
        getDataAdapter.clear();
        getDataAdapter.addAll(newList);

        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

**Publikasi Activity**

```
public class PublikasiActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SearchView.OnQueryTextListener, NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
    ArrayList<GetDataAdapter> GetDataAdapter1;

    RecyclerView recyclerView;

    public String ImageServerUrl;
    public String ImageTitleName;

    RecyclerView.LayoutManager linearViewLayoutManager;
    RecyclerViewAdapter recyclerViewadapter;

    private ProgressWheel progressWheel;

    public static String urlPub = url+"publikasi";

    String GET_JSON_DATA_HTTP_URL = urlPub;
    String JSON_ID = "id";
    String JSON_IMAGE_TITLE_NAME = "judul";
    String JSON_IMAGE_URL = "cover";
    String JSON_NOMOR_PUBLIKASI = "no_publikasi";
    String JSON_NOMOR_KATALOG = "no_katalog";
    String JSON_ISBN = "isbn";
    String JSON_DESKRIPSI = "deskripsi";
    String JSON_DOWNLOAD = "file";
    String JSON_RILIS = "rilis";
    String JSON_KATEGORI = "kategori_id";

    JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest ;
    RequestQueue requestQueue ;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_berita);
        getIntent();
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        setTitle("Publikasi");

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.activity_berita);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view_berita);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        GetDataAdapter1 = new ArrayList<>();
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerview_berita);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        linearViewLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearViewLayoutManager);

        progressWheel = (ProgressWheel) findViewById(R.id.progressWheelBerita);
        recyclerViewadapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(GetDataAdapter1, this);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerViewadapter);

        progressWheel.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        JSON_DATA_WEB_CALL();
    }

 @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.option_menu, menu);
        MenuItem menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.search);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(menuItem);
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {

        newText = newText.toLowerCase();
        ArrayList<GetDataAdapter> newList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (GetDataAdapter getBeritaModel : GetDataAdapter1){
            String name = getBeritaModel.getImageTitleName().toLowerCase();
            if (name.contains(newText))
                newList.add(getBeritaModel);
        }
        recyclerViewadapter.setFilter(newList);
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a line of code inside adapter  after the line..

```
 @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder Viewholder, final int position)
```

Like bellow

```
 @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder Viewholder, final int position) 

//add this line of code 

 Viewholder.setIsRecyclable(false);

//......your rest of the code will same
```

for [more details see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45029681/wrong-item-changes-in-recyclerview/45030143#45030143)

I hope it will work for you..best of luck..

Answer (score 0):

```
mySearchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                // Maintain new arraylist for searchview and pass it to adapter.
                ArrayList<Info> searchList = new ArrayList<Info>();
                String search = mySearchView.getQuery().toString().toLowerCase().trim();

                for (int i = 0; i < myInfoArrayList.size(); i++) {
                    String name = myInfoArrayList.get(i).getMyFullName();
                    if (name.toLowerCase().contains(search)) {
                        Info info = myInfoArrayList.get(i);
                        searchList.add(info);

                    }
                }
                if (searchList.size() > 0) {
                    myAdapter = new Adapter(this, searchLis);
                    myRecycler.setAdapter(myAdapter);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {

                if (newText.isEmpty()) {
                    myAdapter = new Adapter(this, myArrayList);
                    myRecyclerView.setAdapter(myAdapter);

                return true;
            }
        });
```